# New Ender 3 power supply turns on but the controller board does not

Tags: creality-ender-3

I just got an Ender 3 a day or two ago and was really excited being that it was my first 3D printer.

I got to work putting it together with little issue. I go to turn it on and the power supply starts up just fine (the fan on, the internal light on) but the mainboard fan isn't running and the screen isn't turning on. I wait a few minutes thinking that it needed to boot up but nothing. I tried reconnecting the red and black power cables and still nothing.

I'm not set up for tearing the thing apart and checking every socket with a voltmeter or something. I've checked the voltage switch and have it set for 115 V for North America. I remember now that when I was moving the bed and it lurched (because the wheels were too tight) the screen might have lit up.

I'm worried that the board might be fried. I don't feel like taking this thing apart and sending it back.

Comment: Please don't take this wrong, but these printers are cheap, mass produced printers, it is highly possible (see [this recent question](/q15796/)) that it is dead on arrival. If you want to tinker, which you better not do since you have warrantees in place, your only option it to look at all connections to the controller board and measure.

Comment: Good point, back to china it goes.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to check basic power connections with multimeter. But indeed if you are not in an emergency, it would be better to send it back. The wires may come loose, I mean on the main board.